# 2 id columns in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, google-colaboratory, primary-key

I am doing a personal project and am using Postgres as the database service. I am accessing that database through google colab and after uploading the data to the database via PGAdmin, I notice my table has 2 ID columns, even though I dropped the id column in the PGAdmin Import/Export interface:

[image: Snippet from Google Colab: ID column and table index?]

My question is is this simply a Google Colab feature or did I do something wrong upon uploading? When I created the table I used the `ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` command to create the `id` column so that second column is the primary key. It just seems weird to have two id columns. Is there anything I can do about it or is it something I should just ignore?

Comment: The first one is probably an artificial number you UI tool uses. It doesn't belong to the database. Try a different UI tool to query the database.

Comment: Thanks very much @TheImpaler . I'll try in a different UI and see what happens but I have a feeling you're right that it is just a google colab thing.

Comment: You can easily verify that by using `order by id desc` or something like `where id > 5` and see what the values are then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @a_horse_with_no_name I'll check that out. Love the username!